# Resize EPS Vector File (Logo) for Outdoor Signage

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, resize, signage

I'm very new to Adobe Illustrator & I'm teaching myself along with youtube videos & adobe training site on how to use it. I have created a personal logo in EPS format but to fit on hats, shirts etc. I need tips on how to use AI to resize the image to a certain pixel size in order to fit properly on 12x36 birch plywood so that I don't lose quality.   Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "EPS" doesn't mean a great deal. EPS can be vector, EPS can be raster, EPS can be both. Turn on Outline Mode in Illustrator `View > Outline` Do you see paths then or just a box? if it's just a box, then you have raster content which can not be easily resized. And, based on your comment below.. it's possible the sign shop person is trying to get the sign *filled* with the art rather than just centering it proportionately. It's impossible to tell without seeing some sample images in relation to the overall size needed.

Comment: It looks like it has paths, so it is a vector image!

Comment: Then I would suspect it's more about proportions than the construction of the art. I mean, if you've got a 36x12" sign, a square or round logo is just going to be a 10-11" object in the center of it -- unless the artwork is adjusted to make use of the 36" width. If you do just want something centered in the middle of the sign, you probably need to convey that to the sign shop.

Comment: The logo/art is of retangular shape actually but possesses appx 4 "holes" within the art as well. I think I will revisit the signage shop about all the details (dimensions, resizing etc.) or other info that I failed to fully convey  and lack understanding of. This is all new for me but I certainly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on if your EPS is a vector file or raster file.

If it's a vector file, you need to do nothing...vector files can scale to any size and retain quality. If it's a raster file, you will lose quality enlarging it. Sometimes that's a big deal, sometimes it's not. It depends on a lot of factors.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply...most definitely appreciate it. It is a vector image file which is my logo & tradename on it. I took it to a local graphics signage co., the designer says she would have to basically "do alot" like stretching it was term she used or I could have it done by an outside designer to avoid her cost for time it takes so I rather try it myself first.

Comment: When I try and imagine what "she" meant, I envision that perhaps you were asking her to put a 1:1 aspect "square" (the region that the logo takes up) on a 1:3 rectangle (12x36) and you want it edge-to-edge which would entail a re-design of the components instead of stretching it.